# Is this a fair game (three players throw dice)?

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, dice

I found an interview question online summarized as follows:

> Three players A, B, and C are playing a game. A throws three fair 6-sided dice (each one has face values from 1 to 6), while B and C each throws a fair 20-sided die (each one has face values from 1 to 20). Whoever gets a bigger number (or sum of numbers for A) wins the game. Is this a fair game? You can only calculate by hand and have only 10 minutes.

The method I thought of is calculate the probabilities of A wins and B wins respectively, and check whether they are equal. The probability of A wins can be calculated as follows:

$$
P(A>B, A>C)=\sum_{a}P(A>B,A>C|A=a)P(A=a)\\
=\sum_a P(A>B|A=a)P(A>C|A=a)P(A=a)
=\sum_a (\frac{a-1}{20})^2P(A=a)\\
=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[(\frac{A-1}{20})^2]=\frac{1}{400}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A^2-2A+1]
=\frac{1}{400}(\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A^2]-2\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A]+1).
$$

If we denote $X_1,X_2,X_3$ as the three 6-sided dice of A, then we have
$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A]=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_1+X_2+X_3]=3\cdot \frac{1+6}{2}=\frac{21}{2},
$$
and
$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A^2]=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[(X_1+X_2+X_3)^2]=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+2X_1X_2+2X_1X_3+2X_2X_3]\\
=3\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_1^2]+6\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_1X_2]=3\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_1^2]+6\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_1]\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X_2]\\
=3 \cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{6\cdot (6+1)\cdot (6*2+1)}{6}+6\cdot \frac{1+6}{2} \cdot \frac{1+6}{2}=119.
$$
Thus $$P(A>B,A>C)=\frac{1}{400}\cdot (119-2\cdot \frac{21}{2}+1)=\frac{99}{400}.$$

However, here comes the problem when I calculate $P(B>A,B>C)$ as follows:
$$
P(B>A, B>C)=\sum_{b}P(B>A,B>C|B=b)P(B=b)\\
=\sum_b P(B>A|B=b)P(B>C|B=b)P(B=b)
=\sum_b P(B>A|B=b)\cdot \frac{b-1}{20}\cdot P(B=b).
$$
I can't find an easy way to calculate $P(B>A|B=b)$ because the probability distribution of $A$ isn't as simple as $B$ or $C$. In fact, for $a$ from $3$ to $18$, $P(A=a)$ is $\frac{1}{216}\{1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 25, 27, 27, 25, 21, 15, 10, 6, 3, 1\}$. I can't find a general formula for these values or partial sum of these values. And if you calculate the probability with these values directly, it is very time-consuming and I don't think it is feasible when you are being interviewed. Thus I think there may be some more simple method to solve this problem (maybe by symmetry or whatever). For your convenience, with the help of my computer, I get that $P(B>A,B>C)=\frac{543}{1600}=\frac{135.75}{400}>P(A>B,A>C)$. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: @lulu A indeed has the same expected value as B and C, but this is not equal to this is a fair game, neither equal to A can win 1/3 of the games. Suppose that A can be 1 or -1, B can be 2 or -2, C can be 3 or -3, and you can verify that C can win 1/2 of the games in the long run while A and B can each win 1/4 of the games in the long run.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I thought you were asking if it was fair for one player against the other two, which it clearly is not.  I deleted my comment when I realized it was irrelevant.

Comment: What happens in a tie?

Comment: @MatthewConroy In the case of a tie, no one wins.

Comment: This is an old question but just to provide some intuitive solutions here. We can first consider the case of only $A$ and $B$. Then their chance is equal by symmetry of their distribution and equivalence of expected value. Now suppose we add $n$ more players of $B$, as $n \to \infty$ some $B$ will hit on the region [19,21] and guarantees a win with probability $1$. So it is unfair for $A$ to add more players, and thus the case $A, B, C$ hold as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how you can actually proceed with *your own solution* (or at least the same idea!) until you reach the conclusion. Still not sure it can be done within 10 min on an interview, though.

The probability for $A$ to win:

$$P(A\text{ wins})=P(A>B>C)+P(A>B=C)+P(A>C>B)$$

The probability for $B$ to win:

$$P(B\text{ wins})=P(B>A>C)+P(B>A=C)+P(B>C>A)$$

Now, because of overall symmetry:

$$P(A>B>C)=P(B>C>A)$$
$$P(A>B=C)=\frac{1}{20}P(A>B)=\frac{1}{20}P(B>A)=P(B>A=C)$$

so we only need to compare the remaining terms: $P(A>C>B)$ and $P(B>A>C)$. You can calculate those in the same way as you have already calculated $P(A>B\land A>C)$:

$$P(A>C>B)=\sum_{a}P(a>C>B)P(A=a)=\frac{1}{400}\sum_{a}\frac{(a-1)(a-2)}{2}P(A=a)=\frac{1}{400}\left[\frac{1}{2}E(A^2)-\frac{3}{2}E(A)+1\right]=\frac{1}{400}\left(\frac{119}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\frac{21}{2}+1\right)=\frac{179}{1600}$$

$$P(B>A>C)=\sum_{a}P(B>a>C)P(A=a)=\frac{1}{400}\sum_{a}(20-a)(a-1)P(A=a)=\frac{1}{400}(-E(A^2)+21E(A)-20)=\frac{1}{400}(-119+21\frac{21}{2}-20)=\frac{163}{800}=\frac{326}{1600}$$

and obviously $P(B>A>C)>P(A>C>B)$, thus $P(B\text{ wins})>P(A\text{wins})$.

**Addendum/Check step:** We can now additionally calculate $P(A=B)=\frac{1}{20}$ and so $P(A>B)=\frac{1}{2}P(A\ne B)=\frac{19}{40}$ so $P(A>B=C)=\frac{1}{20}P(A>B)=\frac{19}{800}=\frac{38}{1600}$. Thus, $P(A\text{ wins})=\frac{179}{1600}+\frac{38}{1600}+\frac{179}{1600}=\frac{396}{1600}=\frac{99}{400}$, which matches your result. Similarly, $P(B\text{ wins})=\frac{326}{1600}+\frac{38}{1600}+\frac{179}{1600}=\frac{543}{1600}$, which again matches your result.

Comment: That inspired me a lot, thanks! Actually I have found a simple and direct way to calculate $P(B>A,B>C)$ (please see the answer I posted).

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, $P(B>A, B>C) = P(C>A, C>B)$

$\begin{align}P(B>A, B>C) \cdot 2= 1 &- P(A>B,A>C) \\&- P(A=B=C) \\&- P(A=B, A>C) \\&- P(A=C, A>B) \\&-P(B=C, A<B)\end{align}$

$P(A>B,A>C)=\frac{99}{400}$ as obtained in the question

$P(A=B=C) = \frac1{20}^2 = \frac{1}{400}$

$P(A>B)=\sum\limits_{a}P(A>B|A=a)\cdot P(A=a)
=\sum\limits_a (\frac{a-1}{20})\cdot P(A=a)
=\frac{1}{20}(\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A]-1)=\frac{9.5}{20}$

$P(A=C, A>B)= \sum\limits_a P(A=C|A=a)\cdot P(A>B|A=a)\cdot  P(A=a)= \frac1{20} \cdot P(A>B)  =  \frac{9.5}{400}$

Similarly for $P(A=B, A>B)$ and $P(B=C, A<B)$

$P(B>A, B>C) = 0.5* (1 - \frac{99}{400} - \frac1{400} - 3\cdot \frac{9.5}{400}) = \frac{135.75}{400}$

Comment: One doubtful part is how we can directly get $P(A=C,A>B)=P(A=C)⋅P(A>B)$? Although it is true if we use conditional probability to expand the left part, but since you directly write this formula so I assume you think the event $A=C$ and $A>B$ are independent of each other, but you need to prove this first.

Comment: Still thanks a lot! Actually I have found a simple and direct way to calculate $P(B>A,B>C)$ (please see the answer I posted).

Comment: Good comment, thinking of it as $P(A>B, A=C) = P(A>B|A=C)\cdot P(A=C)$ it is readily apparent.  Thinking of it as $P(A>B, A=C) = P(A=C|A>B)\cdot P(A>B)$ it is less apparent but still works out the same way.  Will add a step to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer that it is clearly not fair and biased against $A$.  The expectation values are the same for each player at $10.5$ but $B$ and $C$ have a wider distribution than $A$.  As you are looking for the maximum of three numbers, a wider distribution is to your advantage.  Let me be another player and give me a coin that says $0$ on one face and $21$ on the other.  I win half the time.  Similarly, if you give $A$ a one sided die with $10.5$ on it he wins only $\frac 14$ of the time against the two d$20$s.  His actual $3$d$6$ is between the one sided die and a d$20$, so he will win less than his share.  We were not asked for a specific winning probability for $A$, just whether it was $\frac 13$.

Comment: I don't think "a wider distribution is to your advantage" is true here because if we remove player C, and you can verify that A and B has the same probability of winning and both are equal to $19/40$, but B still has a wider distribution than A. Thus when we add player C, we have no reason to directly jump to your conclusion since it is false under the two players case. Another doubtful part is that even if $P(A wins)<1/3$, we don't know whether $P(B wins)>1/3$ because there are cases where a tie is reached.

Comment: @Daniel:  having more opponents is key.  The max of a number of random numbers is biased high compared to the mean.  The wider the distribution, the higher it will be biased, as hinted by my coin example.  As an interview question I would be much more interested in giving this answer and showing how I would think about it than doing a detailed calculation and getting a number.

Comment: In your example, if we give A a one sided die with 10.5 as you said, and remove C, then P(A wins)=P(B wins) although B has a much wider distribution. But when we adding C, the results totally changed. Thus you cannot reach any conclusion about what the effect of the width of distribution can bring to the game. Since the key part is adding more players, you need to explain clearly why adding more players is biased against A, but your coin example is basically about the width of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve the problem that someone significantly faster at hand computation than I may conceivably carry out in ten minutes.

We are going to show that the probability $P_A$ that $A$ **does not lose** is strictly less than $\frac{1}{3}$; hence that the game is unfair.  Having rolled a $k$, $A$ does not lose if $\max(B,C) \leq k$ or if $\max(B,C) > k$, but $B$ and $C$ are tied.  Therefore:

$$ \begin{align}
P_A &= \sum_{3 \leq k \leq 18} \Big[\Pr(\max(B,C) \leq k) + \Pr(B = C > k) \Big] \cdot \Pr(A=k) \\
&= \sum_{3 \leq k \leq 18} \frac{k^2 + 20 -k}{20^2} \Pr(A=k) \enspace. 
\end{align} $$

Knowing that for $3 \leq k \leq 18$, the values of $\Pr(A = k)$ are

$$ 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 25, 27, 27, 25, 21, 15, 10, 6, 3, 1 \enspace,$$

all divided by $6^3$, we conclude that $P_A = \frac{257}{800}$, which is approximately $0.3212$. Alternatively, that

$$ \frac{257}{800} = \frac{771}{2400} < \frac{800}{2400} = \frac{1}{3} \enspace. $$

This approach also lends itself to the computation of the probability that $A$ wins:

$$ \sum_{3 \leq k \leq 18} \Pr(\max(B,C) < k) \cdot \Pr(A=k) = \sum_{3 \leq k \leq 18} \frac{(k-1)^2}{20^2} \cdot \Pr(A=k) = \frac{99}{400} \enspace, $$

in agreement with what found by others.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @user8734617 and @GHx, I have found a simple and direct way to calculate $P(B>A, B>C)$ as follows:
$$
P(B>A, B>C)=\sum_{a}P(B>a,B>C)P(A=a)\\
=\sum_a \frac{(19+a)(19-(a-1))}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{400}\cdot P(A=a)
=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\frac{380+A-A^2}{800}]\\
=\frac{1}{800}(-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A^2]+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A]+380)
=\frac{1}{800}\cdot (-119+\frac{21}{2}+380)\\
=\frac{543}{1600}=\frac{135.75}{400}>\frac{99}{400}=P(A>B,A>C).
$$

Comment: Upvoted. Well done. Of course the question remains whether there is an easier way to see that B wins more readily than A, without doing all this calculation, with a not-a-hand-wavy argument...

Comment: Very nice, upvoted.