# Question on a dice tossing game

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

This is an interview question I found online, yet I am still uncertain about how it works

> Two player A, B are playing a game. A throws three fair 6-sided dice (each one has face values from 1 to 6), while B throws a fair 20-sided die (each one has face values from 1 to 20). Whoever gets a bigger number (or sum of numbers for A) wins the game. Is this a fair game?

So I have read a few people's answer on the net, and still not knowing how it works. But I have one approach here (very native) and would love to see whether it is a way out.

> As the expected value of 3 dice $= 3 * 7/2 = 10.5$ = the expected
> value of the 20 sided dice. Therefore we may conclude that they are the
> same and hence a fair game? Seems too good to be true. And later proven wrong in the variant question.

And then a variant of the question:

> Now another player C joins, also with a 20 sided dice. Is the game now fair?

From other's answer: it is now unfair. Somehow adding another 20 sided dice makes the game being unfair. I can't get the intuition for the whole set of question.

Appreciate if anyone can help me with getting some intuitive explanation for this question, as I don't really understand the logic behind the whole set. (Perhaps some idea on the original question but proven wrong)

Reference: [Is this a fair game (three players throw dice)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610668/is-this-a-fair-game-three-players-throw-dice)

Comment: Here's a much simpler example illustrating the same problem. I have a die with $1$ and $3$ on it, you have a die with just a $2$ on it. We each win half the time, so it's a fair game. Now a third person comes with a $1$ and $3$ die. Now the only way you can win is if the third person and I both throw $1$, which is one-fourth the time, so it's not a fair game. Understood?

Comment: Interesting... I think I understand your logic. Just one thought, can I generalize that for 2 player scenario, as long as the expected value are the same, it will be a fair game? While for multiple players, it depends on the distribution of the variable (in this case, the sum of the dice)

Comment: If my die has $1,5,6$, and yours has just $4$, we both have expected value $4$, but I win two times out of three.

Comment: Hmmm... then how do we get the "symmetry" intuition for the 2 players case. Cuz I can see people saying quickly that by symmetry 3 6-sided dice and 1 20-sided dice have the same probability of winning. And I simply don't understand where the symmetry come from.

Comment: Or is it actually talking about the distribution of the number is symmetrical (i.e. the distribution of the sum of 3 dice are somewhat like normal distribution but in discrete form (concentrated in the mean but also in symmetry), while the 20sided one is Uni(1, 20), also symmetrical. So if the two distributions are symmetrical with the same mean (10.5), it is fair?

Comment: I think that if both distributions are symmetrical around the same mean, then the two-person game is fair. Maybe it will be a good exercise for you, to try to prove this. Perhaps it can be done by setting up a one-one correspondence between outcomes where the first person wins, and outcomes where the second person wins.